# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack

Tags: linux

I am seeking help for installation in ubuntu 14.04. I am installing a package in my pc. They have their makefiles. I have to run make.

When I did I found error like.....

```
gfortran -O2 -fopenmp -msse2 -o nmbnd.run p_nmbnd.o i_main.o m_getwsr.o ../IOLIB/*.o ../ATOM/*.o ../BNDASA/*.o ../EXTENS/*.o ../FINDES/*.o ../LATTICE/*.o ../SAMPLE/*.o ../TETRA/*.o ../IOCTRL/*.o ../LMIO/*.o ../MAINA/*.o ../NMTO/*.o ../SYM/*.o ../TBSTR/*.o ../CHAPOT/*.o  -L/usr/share/doc/liblapack -llapack -L/usr/share/doc/libblas -lblas 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [nmbnd.run] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/santuphys/NMTO-47.ZB.28/06.gfort/MAIN'
make[1]: *** [cleanmake] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/santuphys/NMTO-47.ZB.28/06.gfort/MAIN'
make: *** [ooo.dep] Error 2
```

I tried all the other similar questions in this forum about link, but I could not resolve it. I specified the path to `Lapack` and `Lblas` in my pc also writing...

```
LAPACK_LIB=   -L/usr/lib/ -llapack  -lblas
```

It did not work. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the lapack and lblas packages installed? can you find the files /usr/lib/libblas.so and /usr/lib/liblapack.so ?

Comment: For me, this did the trick: `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev`

Answer (score 83):

On Ubuntu, make sure you have the packages

- liblapack-dev
- libopenblas-dev

installed:

```
sudo apt install liblapack-dev libopenblas-dev
```

After that, "-L/usr/lib -llapack -lblas" should work. Also note that, as already mentioned in another answer, in the output you showed, you have "-L/usr/share/doc/liblacpack -L/usr/share/doc/libblas", which is certainly not what you want.

Comment: ubuntu one-liner for the lazy `sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev -y ; sudo apt-get install liblapack3 -y ; sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base -y ; sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev -y ;`

Comment: time saver! you may need to run apt-get update before or apt-get -f install after if runing into issues.

Comment: `sudo apt install liblapack-dev libopenblas-dev` is enough for 16.04

Comment: This was only a partial solution in my case (trying to compile an R package, that is "qwraps2"). I succeeded after applying also the solution proposed below, the one regarding the missing symbolic link to libgfortran.so

Answer (score 2):

Just install packages that contain liblapack.so.* and libblas.so.* libraries. 
If you are sure that those packages are already installed - just find them by:
find / -name 'liblapack*' and add that path to gcc with -L/path/to/liblapack.

edit: In your invocation of fortran compiler there are some directories given with -L - but are you sure that needed libraries are located in *documentation* directories:
-L/usr/share/doc/liblapack  -L/usr/share/doc/libblas
?

Answer (score 1):

My error was like this:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran

I solved the problem following this post in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510176/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcudart)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgfortran.so /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
```

N.B. I know this is an old post. But I spent a lot of time to solve this and in the end, it was very simple. I hope others having the same problem can solve this very quickly.

Comment: In addition, to get the location of your library, you can use "locate gfortran.so"

Comment: Very helpful, not only I needed to install libgfortran-5-dev (Ubuntu 18.04) but indeed the above symbolic link was necessary to the compilation work.