# Installing liblapack without root permissions? (Trying to get Armadillo/Lapack/Blas working)

Tags: installation, centos, lapack, armadillo

I'm trying to install Armadillo (and thus also BLAS and LAPACK) on a linux server for which I do not have root permission. I have jumped through a few of the first hurdles, but I am getting an error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033243/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llapack) addresses the same problem, with the solution being to install

- liblapack-dev
- liblapack3
- libopenblas-base
- libopenblas-dev

The problem is the only way I've found to do this online is by doing something like sudo-aptget install or yum install. Both are not allowed on the server I use. I can download binaries and install them locally - that is it.

My question is: how can I install these packages without the above permissions and get on my way to using Armadillo?

I'm using Centos linux, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have root permissions, the best way is to download and build LAPACK and BLAS. You can download the source code from [netlib](http://www.netlib.org).

Description of installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node14.html) and [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn81/node10.html).

The basic steps are:

- Unzip and tar the file.
- Copy and edit the file LAPACK/make.inc.example to LAPACK/make.inc.
- Edit the file LAPACK/Makefile
- type make.

Similarly you can download and build [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node11.html).