# Unable to install package car

Tags: r, 64-bit, linux-mint, install.packages, r-car

I am using R version 3.2.3 in Linux mint 17.3 64 bit. I was trying to install the package "car" with `dependencies=TRUE`, but the installation failed with the following error messages:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘leaps’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘lmtest’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘SparseM’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘quantreg’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
9: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘effects’ had non-zero exit status
10: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
11: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
12: In install.packages("car", dependencies = T) :
installation of package ‘alr4’ had non-zero exit status
```

How do I resolve the issue? Please help.

Comment: The answer here may explain your error: [“installation of package 'FILE_PATH' had non-zero exit status” in R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894019/3560695)

Comment: trying to manually install the dependent packages has worked for me before `install.packages("minqa")` and then go down the line until all dependencies have been installed.

Comment: Installation of the package "minqa" itself is also giving error.

Comment: What *kind* of error? The one with an error message?

Comment: `* installing *source* package ‘minqa’ ...`
`** package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`
`** libs`
`gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o`
`/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found`
`make: *** [altmov.o] Error 127`
`ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’`
`* removing ‘/home/bishwarup/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/minqa’`
`Warning in install.packages :`
  `installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 and RStudio 4.2.1 (as of October 2022) and NO solution below works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the solution. After looking at the error message for installing "minqa", I realized that the installer was unable to find `gfortran`. So I installed gfortran,then tried to install "car" again. This time I got another error message saying that `-llapack  -lblas` were not found. Therefore, according to this link: [/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033243/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llapack)
I installed packages `"liblapack-dev"`, `"liblapack3"`, `"libopenblas-base"` and `"libopenblas-dev"`. After that, the "car" package was successfully installed.

Answer (score 7):

Install r-cran-car

Installing r-cran-car package on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) is as easy as running the following command on terminal:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-cran-car

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case it was enough to install `gcc-fortran` on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Anaconda, consider installing the gfortran package via conda. For example, [on Mac](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gfortran_osx-64):

```
conda install -c anaconda gfortran_osx-64
```

Answer (score 0):

When browsing through the output of `install.packages("car")`, I had the next error messages:

```
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
```

After added the related packages to my `Ubuntu` system, everything worked fine.

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran liblapack-dev libblas-dev
```