# Installing lmtest package source

Tags: r

I'm wanting to install lmtest's source code. I tried the following, and got an error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/lmtest_0.9-34.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")

trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/lmtest_0.9-34.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 180257 bytes (176 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 176 KB

> * installing *source* package ‘lmtest’ ...
> ** package ‘lmtest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c pan.f -o pan.o make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory make: *** [pan.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lmtest’
> * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/lmtest’
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
> ‘/var/folders/z6/1rpmk8d971n2864kd2d514g40000gn/T//RtmpXtgPIq/downloaded_packages/lmtest_0.9-34.tar.gz’
> had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory` This probably is leading to error. Make a folder and try to re-install

Answer (score 1):

`lmtest` depends on the package `car`. [A related question has been posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647650/unable-to-install-package-car) about issues installing `car`. OP responded with [additional details on resolving the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35650554/2576935).

One of the issues is that gfortran is not available which is a system package. In my experience the "non-zero exit status" has been because the package relies on a system package that isn't available.