# semPlot package dependency issues

Tags: r, package, linux-mint, semplot

I am trying to use the package `semPlot` with R version 3.2.3 on Linux Mint. Is the only solution to downgrade my R-version? I have installed package XML without errors. UPDATE BELOW

ran: `install.packages("semPlot",dependencies=T)` errors:

```
....
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c minqa.cpp -o minqa.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [minqa.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/minqa’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘nloptr’ ...
** package ‘nloptr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmpw7bRnY/R.INSTALL5fd12b68373/nloptr':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/nloptr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [RcppEigen.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘arm’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/arm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘arm’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘rockchalk’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rockchalk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rockchalk’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘arm’ is not available for package ‘mi’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mi’ is not available for package ‘sem’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sem’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sem’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘sem’ is not available for package ‘qgraph’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/qgraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘qgraph’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘qgraph’, ‘sem’, ‘rockchalk’ are not available for package ‘semPlot’
* removing ‘/home/king/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/semPlot’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘semPlot’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpW1PZ2x/downloaded_packages’
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the comments I discovered I had to install:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I am now getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks again to the comments I discovered I had to install:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

which finally fixed my issues and I was able to install the package

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: You know that you can install more than one R version on a system?

Comment: But your actual problem seems to be that your compiler doesn't work/exist. I don't believe that an older R version will help with that.

Comment: I forgot to include the fact that I am running Linux mint above.... Does that help explain the compiler error?

Comment: @Roland, Thanks to your comment about the compiler I got a step further in solving this. Any other ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033243/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llapack