# R : /usr/bin/ld : cannot find -llapck

Tags: r

I tried to install kernlab package and it gives me this error :

Any ideas to solve it ?

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -llapack
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6 : la recette pour la cible « kernlab.so » a échouée
make: *** [kernlab.so] Erreur 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘kernlab’
* removing ‘/home/nicolas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/kernlab’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kernlab’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpRgMaIl/downloaded_packages’
```

> EDIT : I solved it by installing these package (I'm under linux mint ):

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev -y ; sudo apt-get install liblapack3 -y ; sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base -y ; sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev -y ;
```

Comment: What is your R version? I just download it and it works fine.

Comment: R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

Comment: Try to download Full R development environment metapackage via the software package manager.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033243/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llapack

Comment: That works ! I edited my question to put the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try

- `install.packages('kernlab', dependencies = TRUE)`
- Change cran mirrors
- Use command line directly: `R CMD INSTALL kernlab_0.9-24.tar.gz`, after [downloading the package](http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/CRAN/src/contrib/00Archive/kernlab/).

If this does not work download "Full R development environment metapackage"